# Can I format gson JsonWriter to something readable?

Tags: java, json, format, gson

I have wrote a program using gson's JsonWriter to create a json file, the creating the json file works well but it gives me formatted json not the best seeing I want to be able to edit this file by hand easily too

example: The program gives me

```
{"bells":{"category":"hostile","sounds":["bells"]},"ankylosaurus":{"category":"hostile","sounds":["dinosaurs/ankylosaurus/AnkylosaurusCall1","dinosaurs/ankylosaurus/AnkylosaurusCall2","dinosaurs/ankylosaurus/AnkylosaurusRoar1","dinosaurs/ankylosaurus/AnkylosaurusRoar2","dinosaurs/ankylosaurus/AnkylosaurusSay1","dinosaurs/ankylosaurus/AnkylosaurusSay2"]},...
```

But I would like it exported as

```
{
"bells":{
    "category":"hostile",
    "sounds":[
        "bells"
    ]
},
"ankylosaurus":{
    "category":"hostile",
    "sounds":[
        "dinosaurs/ankylosaurus/AnkylosaurusCall1",
        "dinosaurs/ankylosaurus/AnkylosaurusCall2",
        "dinosaurs/ankylosaurus/AnkylosaurusRoar1",
        "dinosaurs/ankylosaurus/AnkylosaurusRoar2",
        "dinosaurs/ankylosaurus/AnkylosaurusSay1",
        "dinosaurs/ankylosaurus/AnkylosaurusSay2"
    ]
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Gson` is more versatile than the `JsonWriter` and has the "pretty printing" option.

You can use it to write to a stream like this :

```
private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setPrettyPrinting()
    .create();

OutputStreamWriter writer = ...
writer.write(gson.toJson(object));
```

Comment: So will Swapping over to Gson instead of JsonWriter be tricky or just straight forward

Comment: I only use the Gson as it makes one only configuration in one place (you might have other things to configure in the future, like specific (un)serializations). There's nothing complex, I don't see where you might have problems swapping.

Comment: What I can see on google how Gson works compared to what I've done with JsonWriter might come in handy with what I need to do next in my program thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Enable Pretty printing :)

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(yourDataHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using the `JsonWriter` you can [specify an indent](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html#setIndent(java.lang.String)) to achieve what you want:

```
jsonWriter.setIndent("    ");
```